# HTML truncated because of NULL character

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I am downloading HTML from a server (one that I cannot control), and sometimes the response will include a `NULL` character in the middle somewhere. Because of this, the response is being truncated at that point. How do I remove that `NULL` character and prevent it from being truncated? Here's the code I'm using:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *_request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [DEFAULTS objectForKey:@"gradespeed_url"], @"ParentStudentGrades.aspx"]]];
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request = _request;
[request setAllowCompressedResponse:NO];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSData *response_data = [request responseData];
    NSString *response_string = [request responseString];
}];
```

The `NSString` is truncated, but maybe it's possible to manipulate the `NSData`? 
Please advise.

Comment: ASIHTTP is ancient, even the author suggests not to use it. The current in-vogue library is AFNetworking.

Comment: Thanks, I realize this, but it does not solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I discovered was actually quite simple. I just needed to add the following code to remove the random NULL characters:

```
response_string = [response_string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\0" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on `[request responseString]` do your own conversion from `[request responseData]` handling the null as appropriate.

Or examine the ASIHTTP code to find out exactly what is happening.